# Subsequent edited tags and scores

Tags: support, tags, edits, tag-score

Let's say there is a question and I add a tag subsequently by editing it. This question already has answers with some upvotes. Would the added tag affect the scores of the users for that tag?

Comment: Yes, the next time the tag score calculation runs.