# Tag stats don't get updated when tags in questions are edited

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-score

Usually tag-score is updated ([daily or within a short time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253292/when-does-the-top-users-statistics-get-updated)) after tags in a question are edited. For example suppose I post an answer for a question tagged **C** and I get 2 upvotes, now if question is edited to include **Algorithms** tag after some time I'll have a score of two on both **C** and **Algorithms** tag (as also confirmed short time ago [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255994/subsequent-edited-tags-and-scores)).

It seems not working any more, number of questions/answers for that tag is displayed right but tag-score isn't recalculated. Is this a bug, a change or SE scripts are having fun under sun in a Pacific Ocean island?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The daily tag update script has failed to run in the last few days.

I have eliminated the direct cause, but it may take a couple of days for the script to execute correctly (it depends on other cleanup scripts running to completion beforehand).